# Error while sending mail - The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0, smtpclient

i have tried mostly every example available on net but still no working,whenever i click on submit button it shows this error ,please anyone help me with this

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    DAL.s_email = txtforget.Text;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = BAL.forgot_pass(DAL);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("my@email.com");
        msg.To.Add(txtforget.Text);
        msg.Subject = "Yor Password details";
        msg.Body = "Hi,<br>Please check your Login Details<br/><br/> Your Username : " + dt.Rows[0]["Username"] + "<br/><br/> Your Password " + dt.Rows[0]["Password"] + "<br/><br/>";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my@email.com", "****");                       
        smtp.Send(msg);
        Label2.Text = "your username and password is sent";
        txtforget.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        Label2.Text = "Email is not registered";
    }
}
```

web config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="my@email.com">
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="****" port="587" userName="my@email.com"  defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: what is error?show it.

Comment: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Comment: have you tried it with `EnableSsl=false`?

Comment: yes tried, but it gives an error -
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. dk1sm19134965pbc.46 - gsmtp

Comment: Your code actually works, I tried it with my own gmail credentials and it works fine. Just check your credentials again sure there's some mistake in the username or password. Also make sure you're sending from a gmail account.

Comment: thanks,i had to create another gmail acct for that and worked ,but why it was not working with previous gmail account ?any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
  {


        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(toemail);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("my@email.com");
        mail.Subject = "Mail";
                mail.Body = "  Hi,<br>Please check your Login Details<br/><br/> Your Username : " + dt.Rows[0]["Username"] + "<br/><br/> Your Password " + dt.Rows[0]["Password"] + "<br/><br/>";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my@email.com", "password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

Comment: still same error,i have tried many solutions from last 3 days but same error every time

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I wasn't able to find anything helpful in other posts. Be sure to check that your msg.From email is correct:

```
msg.From = new MailAddress("my@email.com");
```

Your mail server may successfully authenticate your credentials but reject your from email. To help explain what I'm talking about, here is a possible mail server's response:

```
--> 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
Authenticated as credentials@email.com
<-- MAIL FROM:<from@email.com>
530 5.7.0 Authentication required
Connection closed
SMTP session terminated (Bytes in/out: 482/955)
```